# How can I use reflection to find the properties which implement a specific interface?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, interface

Consider this example:

```
public interface IAnimal
{
}

public class Cat: IAnimal
{
}

public class DoStuff
{
    private Object catList = new List<Cat>();

    public void Go()
    {
        // I want to do this, but using reflection instead:
        if (catList is IEnumerable<IAnimal>)
            MessageBox.Show("animal list found");

        // now to try and do the above using reflection...
        PropertyInfo[] properties = this.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            //... what do I do here?
            // if (*something*)
                MessageBox.Show("animal list found");
        }
    }
}
```

Can you complete the if statement, replacing *something* with the correct code?

**EDIT:**

I noticed that I should have used a property instead of a field for this to work, so it should be:

```
    public Object catList
    {
        get
        {
          return new List<Cat>();
        }
    }
```

Comment: no.  It is not homework.

Comment: @bzlm, who would give him this as a homework? lock at his profile he is 33..

Comment: @shuhel I think there are some things you need to learn about the Internet...

Comment: Instead of simply copying and pasting my business software problem into this screen I spent some time simplifying it so that it would be easier for other people to help me to solve this problem.  That's probably why bzlm thought it looked like homework.  I actually am 33... but I don't always act like it :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can look at the properties' `PropertyType`, then use `IsAssignableFrom`, which I assume is what you want:

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = this.GetType().GetProperties();
foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
    if (typeof(IEnumerable<IAnimal>).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
    {
        // Found a property that is an IEnumerable<IAnimal>
    }                           
}
```

Of course, you need to add a property to your class if you want the above code to work ;-)

Comment: The problem might be that you type the value as a object - and you can assign anything to object. So if you want to keep that, you might need to look at the runtime value of the property, assuming you have a value.

Comment: I don't think this would work - shouldn't this be `if((typeof(IEnumerable<IAnimal>).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))` ??

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it is just call `GetProperties()` on the interface from within the object, opposed to on the object itself.

```
public static void DisplayObjectInterface(object source, Type InterfaceName)
{
    // Get the interface we are interested in
    var Interface = source.GetType().GetInterface(InterfaceName.Name);
    if (Interface != null)
    {
        // Get the properties from the interface, instead of our source.
        var propertyList = Interface.GetProperties();
        foreach (var property in propertyList)
            Debug.Log(InterfaceName.Name + " : " + property.Name + "Value " + property.GetValue(source, null));
    }
    else
        Debug.Log("Warning: Interface does not belong to object.");

}
```

I like to make `InterfaceName` parameter a `Type` to avoid any typo errors when looking up `GetInterface()` by string name.

Usage:

```
DisplayObjectInterface(Obj, typeof(InterFaceNameGoesHere));
```

**EDIT**: I just noticed that your example was a collection, this will not work on a collection passed as a whole. You would have to pass each item individually. I'm tempted to delete but this will probably help others that google this same question looking for a non-collection solution.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that in your example, catList would not be found with `GetType().GetProperties ()`.  You would use `GetType().GetFields ()` instead.

If you are trying to determine whether the property is defined as IEnumerable you can do this:

```
if (typeof(IEnumerable<IAnimal>) == property.PropertyType)
{
   MessageBox.Show("animal list found");
}
```

If you want to know if you can assign the value of the property into a `IEnumerable<IAnimal>`, do this:

```
if (typeof(IEnumerable<IAnimal>).IsAssignableFrom (property.PropertyType))
{
   MessageBox.Show("animal list found");
}
```

If the property type is not specific enough (like `object Animal{get;set;}`) to get your answer, you will need to get the value to decide.  You can do this:

```
object value = property.GetValue(this, null);
if (value is IEnumerable<IAnimal>)
{
   MessageBox.Show("animal list found");
}
```

Comment: As I am reading the question correcyly, the point is to do it without knowing the value, only the Type obtained using reflection.

Comment: I didn't interpret it that way, but I will address that to, just in case.

Comment: For my purposes it doesn't matter whether you're checking the instance or the type... I'm using reflection because I don't know at runtime which properties the containing class will have... if that makes sense.  Anyway, your solution works.  Thanks!